# How to present all values on a crowded axis of a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to plot a graph with the following axis labels:

x-axis values:

```
range(2,52,2) #processors
```

z-axis values:

```
[2<<exponent for exponent in range(10)]#clusters
```

I need the exact values above to appear in the x- and z-axis.

I tried:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

xs = range(2,52,2) #processors
plt.xticks(xs)
ys = range(0, 251) #time
#plt.yticks(ys)
zs = [2<<exponent for exponent in range(10)]#clusters
ax.set_zticks(zs)

# Tweaking display region and labels
ax.set_xlim(2, 52)
ax.set_ylim(0, 251)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1025)
ax.set_xlabel('Number of processors')
ax.set_ylabel('Time')
ax.set_zlabel('Number of clusters')

plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

But I cannot see the exact values of the z-axis. The z-axis does not show the exact values because they overlap!

What is wrong?

Comment: Neither do I understand what you want to plot nor what you want to label. The code seemingly does none of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Mr. T: I have edited the question. Is that clear now?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. If there are too many labels to show in one place, then there are too many labels. [You could of course present your data on a logarithmic axis.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41215272/8881141)

Comment: @Mr. T: Could you help to apply logatihmic scale?